# Xbee Shield - Turning jumper settings into ON/OFF (XBEE/USB) manual switch

Tags: arduino, switches, xbee, enclosure, jumper

I have the following Xbee Shield where I need to constantly switch jumpers in order to allow Xbee communication and/or USB communication.

The following is set for Xbee communication:

[image: Xbee Communication]

*"Xbee Communication"*

The following is set for USB communication:

[image: USB Communication]

*"USB Communication"*

The following is without jumpers (which also acts as USB communication as well):

[image: Without, also USB]

*"Without (also USB)"*

As my Arduino and Xbee Shield are going to sit inside an enclosure with screws and my USB port being quickly available to plug a USB cord into I'd like to attach an ON/OFF switch that acts as XBEE/USB rather than have to unscrew it and manually shift the jumpers into the correct places. I'm not quire sure how to wire up a switch to do this.

Looking from a birds eye view. If the pins are as follows:

```
(1) (2) (3)
(4) (5) (6)
```

Considering that without any jumpers attached, it acts as USB communication. Am I then safe to assume that hooking up a switch like the following is going to be easy?

[image: Switch]

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it's possible!

You just need a 3-pin switch that maps exactly the pins of the jumpers, and that commutes from the right to the left pin.

[These](http://www.alibaba.com/products/3_pin_switch/--100008613.html) are some examples...

Then, to connect it I would suggest to use a connector, so you can always come back to the jumpers way, but this way you usually can't disable both...there are also 3-positions switches that allow also to leave the contacts open.

UPDATE: I don't understand well the part with numbers; you need to keep the 2 jumpers separate, so you can use 2 switches and try to mechanically switch them simultaneously, or maybe you can find a switch that can simultaneously command 2 channels...

Comment: Grazie tanto! Can you see my updated question. I've added some reference numbers, which I'm not so sure of.

Comment: @Fulvio Prego! But the part with numbers has confused me...

Comment: Let's say you're counting from top-left to bottom-right where the top-left is (1) and the bottom-right is (6).

Comment: @Fulvio yes but what are you meaning with "the positive lead is attached to (1) (2) and the negative lead is attached to (4) (5)"?

Comment: I've added a photo of the switch I want to use.

Comment: It would be better with a 3-pins switch, but as you said that disconnected goes into USB mode, so you can use it just to enable XBee mode.

Comment: Ended up going with a 3-pin switch. ON (XBEE) OFF (USB). Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Fulvio glad that you solved! But for the double connector, how did you manage? Double switch?

Comment: I used a 3-connector cable to connect to the left pins (4)(5)(6) and then left (1)(2) connected via jumper and it just works when I hook it up to a 3-pin switch turning ON/OFF.

Comment: @Fulvio ok! So the (1)(2)(3) jumper is for the supply?

Comment: Looks like it, yeah. Works fine with Xbee communication and USB now via the single switch.

Answer (score 1):

Something like [this](http://nz.mouser.com/ProductDetail/CK-Components/S602031TS03Q/?qs=sGAEpiMZZMtHXLepoqNyVf60SUH14WI6OfoB9JGYy3M=)? 
It will connect either of the two Jumper settings but not do the no jumpers at all mode, if thats even neeeded.  Totally use a connector.